# how to paint using stencil mode directly in image editor

Tags: texture-painting

is it possible to paint directly on the image editor but using texture with stencil mode. My object is a cylinder and if i do stencil paint in 3d viewport, i have to go around the surface and because it's curved the texture got stretched/distorted so i think it would be practical just to do the stencil in image editor where the cylinder has been unwarped evenly. But seems i can't do the stencil in image editor , am i correct?

Comment: yes you can use the stencil in the UV/Image Editor, but what do you mean when you say that your texture stretches in the 3D view?

Comment: The texture stretch means when we paint the surfaces which is not perpendicular to the view will has texture stretch. For example :  as in cylinder, the surface near the edge will not facing us. So normally i will rotate view around  and paint only the faces which perpendicular to my view. So i think it will be easier to paint them in image editor where the surface uv has been unwarped flat.

Comment: ok that what I guessed but I wanted to be sure, anyway yes you can use stencil in UV/Image editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the stencil in the Image Editor in 2.8 once you confirm you have usable UVs on your object. Good thing is the Cylinder primitive already comes packaged with basic UV mapping. Just be sure to use the Image Editor to paint and not try the UV Editor since they have been split.
[image]